# That command depends on command in Target 'MyApp' (project 'MyApp'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

I tried deleting, updating, and re-installing pods. Looked for it and there are no duplicate files in Copy Bundle Resources but I'm getting this error and I can't seem to figure out why?

> Multiple commands produce
> 'MY_PATH/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-fniucmthwofzlhdqjqjmozyhxhgt/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.app/Assets.car':
>
> 1. Target 'MyApp' (project 'MyApp') has compile command with
>    input
>    'MY_PROJECT_PATH/Assets.xcassets'
> 2. That command depends on command in Target 'MyApp' (project
>    'MyApp'): script phase “[CP] Copy Pods Resources”

I've also tried clearing the derived data folder using `rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` command but still this error is not going away.

Comment: Maybe one of your pods is misbehaving. Try going back to an old version that worked, and seeing which pods were added since it worked.

Answer (score 23):

--Select the Target.

--Go to Build Phases tab.

--Copy Pods Resources

--Remove the items listed in Output Files or Output Files List

[image]

Comment: amazing thank you, how did you know?